# Angular cli project not building when nesting code inside another folder in src

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created a angular cli project. My code lies inside src folder. I have now created a subfolder inside src named client, and have moved all the code inside client.
I have also updated the angular-cli.json as follows:

```
  apps": [
{
  "root": "src/client",
```

Somehow my app is not buidling and I am getting below error:

ERROR in D:/ccw-dev/ccw-ng/src/client/app/app-routing.module.ts (1,26): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
This is happening in all the files as none of the modules are accesible.
What is my mistake?

Comment: is there app folder inside src ?, what exactly is your folder structure

Comment: try to delete node modules folder and run npm install again, paths probably need to be updated

Comment: either keep you app.module.ts in app folder and everything else wil fall in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses relative URLs in a couple of files located in the src dir, see tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json. After you move your code into a subdirectory, you need to modify these files manually.

If you knew that you wanted src/client to be a root dir before generating the project, you woldn't need to do it manually: `ng new my-proj --source-dir=src/client`